# Как преобразовать комплексное число в double?

Tags: c#

Мне нужно преобразовать два комплексных числа в Double, чтобы в последующем их сравнить. Преобразовать нужно по формуле. Подскажите, как это можно сделать? 
Так я их объявляю:

```
var a = new Complex(A.real, A.image);
var b = new Complex(B.real, B.image);
```

Формула для А и В соответственно:

```
Math.Sqrt(A.real * A.real + A.image * A.image);
Math.Sqrt(B.real * B.real + B.image * B.image);
```

Answer (score 0):

Эти формулы соответствуют модулю (амплитуде) комплексного числа.

Свойство [Magnitude](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.numerics.complex.magnitude?view=netframework-4.8#System_Numerics_Complex_Magnitude) предназначено для его получения.

Однако ничего не мешает и использовать приведённые формулы c Sqrt

Answer (score 0):

```
Complex complex1 = new Complex(2.0, 3.0);
Console.WriteLine("|{0}| = {1:N2}", complex1, Complex.Abs(complex1));
Console.WriteLine("Equal to Magnitude: {0}", 
Complex.Abs(complex1).Equals(complex1.Magnitude));
```